# add onclick event to multiple divs in prototype

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, prototype

I am wondering how to execute a `function` when I click on my currently selected `div` as such:

```
Whatever.prototype.addClick = function() {
  this.current = document.getElementById('div'+i);
  this.current.onclick = function() {alert('hello'); };
  };
```

To clarify, `i` increments by 1 each time a `div` is created, giving each `div` a unique `id`.

Please let me know if anything is unclear or if more code is needed.

Big thanks!

Comment: why are you creating a prototype function when you simply want to add a click handler to multiple divs?I'm just curious..

Comment: this is just a small part of a more complex program. and it's fun :)

Comment: Solved it. The issue was not related to this code snippet.